# Getting NullPointerException for subscribing to Observable in ViewModel during Unit Test

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, rx-java, viewmodel

I'm trying to run a unit test on my ViewModel class but when I run the test I am getting a NullPointerException. getDataManager().getAuthToken() method call an API using retrofit and return a string response. Is there any way to test the method 'startLogin()'? Here is the code.

**LoginViewModelTest.kt**

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class LoginViewModelTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var instantTaskExecutorRule =  InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    companion object {
        @ClassRule
        @JvmField
        val schedulers = RxSchedulerRule()
    }
    private val application = mock(Application::class.java)
    private val dataManager = mock(DataManager::class.java)
    private val serviceConnector = mock(ServiceConnector::class.java)
    private val requestInterceptor = mock(RequestInterceptor::class.java)

    private lateinit var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable
    private lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
        loginViewModel = LoginViewModel(application, dataManager, serviceConnector, compositeDisposable, requestInterceptor)
    }

    @Test
    fun testLoginWithValidQR(){

        val map = QueryMapBuilder.getAuthTokenHeaders()
        val body = TokenReqBody()
        val success = TokenResSuccess()

        `when`(dataManager.getAuthToken(map, body)).thenReturn(Observable.just(success))

        assertNotNull(dataManager.getAuthToken(map, body))

        // got error here
        loginViewModel.startLogin()

    }
}
```

**LoginViewModel.java**

```
public class LoginViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
    private RequestInterceptor mRequestInterceptor;
    private SingleLiveEvent<LoginViewDataEvents> loginViewDataSingleLiveEvent;

    @Inject
    public LoginViewModel(Application application, DataManager dataManager, ServiceConnector serviceConnector, CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable, RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor) {
        super(application, dataManager, serviceConnector, compositeDisposable);
        mRequestInterceptor = requestInterceptor;
        loginViewDataSingleLiveEvent = new SingleLiveEvent<>();
    }

    public void startLogin() {
        Map<String, String> map = QueryMapBuilder.getAuthTokenHeaders();
        TokenReqBody body = QueryMapBuilder.getAuthTokenBody(AppConfig.getConfig());
        getCompositeDisposable().add(getDataManager().getAuthToken(map, body)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //getting error here
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe()
            );
    }

}
```

**Error Logs**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.doc.ui.login.LoginViewModel.startLogin(LoginViewModel.java:102)
at com.example.doc.login.LoginViewModelTest.testLoginWithValidQR(LoginViewModelTest.kt:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at com.example.doc.RxSchedulerRule$apply$1.evaluate(RxSchedulerRule.kt:44)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for getting null inside `startLogin` function is because java passes non-primitive variables by reference, meaning that it passes memory address and not the value itself.
The first use of `dataManager.getAuthToken(map, body)` passes because you are using the same objects `map` and `body` that defined the `'when'` statement (they have the same memory address).
The second time (inside the function), you are using entirely new objects that have a new memory address so the `'when'` statement does not trigger.
A solution for this is to change the `'when'` statement to:

```
`when`(dataManager.getAuthToken(any(), any())).thenReturn(Observable.just(success))
```

Which means that the statement will be triggered with **any** object passed to the function.

Comment: the parameter we are passing to 'when', same should get passed to the actual method only then it will return the same value that we have passed at thenReturn() 
Adding this for those who were not able to understand the above statements written by @Nizan Ifrach

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, in unit test you are creating a new object for DataManager

```
private val dataManager = mock(DataManager::class.java)
```

and using that to call `dataManager.getAuthToken(map, body);`

However, in actual implementation inside LoginViewModel, you use the below line,

```
getDataManager().getAuthToken(map, body)
```

Here getDataManager() is null. So you need to add below line make it work,

```
when(getDataManager()).thenReturn(dataManager);
```